# What is the value of the angle $x$?

Tags: geometry

[image]

$ {ABCD}$  is square. What is the value of the angle $x$?

I currently don't have any idea about this question. Can you assist?

Comment: Hint: Consider the Triangle $AFB$.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I didn't get your hint.

Comment: What is the angle $FBA$ ? ... the triangle is isosceles so ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $\widehat{ABF}=26^\circ$
2. $\widehat{BFA}=77^\circ$ since $BAF$ is isoceles
3. $\widehat{EFB}=103^\circ$
4. $x = 360^\circ -(64^\circ+90^\circ+103^\circ)=\color{red}{103^{\circ}}$.

Comment: How did you find that $\widehat{BFA}=77^\circ$?

Comment: @Liam: $\frac{180-26}{2}=77.$

Comment: Thanks! :) It worked.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Calculate angle FBA, since it and $64^\circ$ make a right angle.

Step 2: Calculate angle BAF, since this is an isosceles triangle (BF=BC, and BC=BA since it's a square).

Step 3: Calculate x, since AB and DC are parallel lines, and we just calculated angle BAF.

Comment: I still couldn't do it :/ Can you be more clear?